# QGIS: How to plot a GPS track color-coded by the altitude (or any other value like speed, ...)?

Tags: qgis, postgis, gpx, plot

I have GPX files recorded from various treks. 
I want to plot them on a QGIS map and have the color of each track segment modified by the altitude recorded.

An idea of the result I am looking for is illustrated on the following picture:
[image]

I have imported GPX files on QGIS as vector layer.
It provided in QGIS a polyline and a serie of points.

[image]

I have managed to color the dots using a style scaled on the data field "ele" (for elevation *in meters*).

[image]

But I am looking to draw the polyline (and keep only the line on the final map).

Comment: You can do it if you break the polyline into line segments. PostGIS can do it (ST_split). Then you can create a thematic map for lines.

Comment: Thank you Zoltan for this hint.  I am not familiar with PostGIS, so I would appreciate if you can recommend any guide or example. Reading the manual, I was wondering if the use [ST_Makeline](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-svn/ST_MakeLine.html/) to create lines from the GPS points may be more appropriate. But I am still working on it...

Comment: ST_Makeline can solve your task, that case you should write some scripts to create lines from from track. AFAIK there is no ready tool for it.

Comment: This question is quite old, but: any updates on that?

Comment: None that I am aware of. Help welcomed.